# Windows 7 black screen after boot animation

Tags: windows-7

This is happening with my windows 7 64-bit install frequently.
Today i was trying to install an icon pack. There was already a restore point prior to it so i didn't feel like create one. 
I replaced the following system files in both system32 and sysWOW64

- imageres.dll
- imagesp1.dll
- zipfldr.dll and
- shell32.dll

After a reboot i see windows boot animation and then a black screen (with no mouse)
I let it like that for 10 minutes and the laptop automatically went to sleep mode. I wake it up and see an error box this error

> "interactive logon failed to initialize"

I close it and i'm left with a black screen again, this time with a mouse though.

I tried using automatic system repair. It just tells me to remove any extra hardware (i have none attached atm)
System restore finishes successfully but doesn't fix the problem.

Safe mode doesn't work either. same black screen after boot animation

Can someone help me with this?

Also, I'll be grateful anyone can upload those default files (listed above) for both system32 and sysWOW64 from a windows 7 64bit install (no service pack)

Comment: You can extract the files from your DVD and replace them yourself instead of depending on something a stranger uploads. Follow [this tutorial](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/42776-extract-files-windows-7-installation-dvd.html) or [this one](http://blog.nirsoft.net/2009/09/17/how-to-extract-missing-system-files-from-the-dvd-of-windows-7vista/).

Comment: +1 on that. Let me try the restoring the files and see if it works

Answer (score 1):

When you get the mouse pointer, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and wait until Task Manager opens. Or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>. Go to the Processes tab and kill explorer.exe if it's running.

Then go to File → "New Task (Run...)", type `explorer` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. That should solve your problem in general case.